# Problems while learning cython

Tags: numpy, cython

I am learning cython to speed up numpy. I wrote a code to see how to optimize numpy array calculation. 
The python code is:

```
from numpy import *

def set_onsite(n):
    a=linspace(0,n,n+1)
    onsite=zeros([n+1,n+1],float)
    for i in range(0,n+1):
        onsite[i,i]=a[i]*a[i]
    return onsite
```

Then, I tried to cythonize this code:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
import cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)

def set_onsite(np.int_t n):
     cdef np.ndarray[double,ndim=1,mode='c'] a=np.linspace(0,n,n+1)
     cdef np.ndarray[double,ndim=2,mode='c'] onsite=np.empty(n+1,n+1)
     cdef np.int_t i

     for i in range(0,n+1):
         onsite[i,i]=a[i]*a[i]
     return onsite
```

After running setup.py file, I got the .so file. I ran the code `%timeit myfile.set_onsite(10000)`,but IPython showed

> TypeError: data type not understood

So could anyone tell me what is going on here? 
I checked my code many times but I did not figure out where the problem arises.

Answer (score 4):

The problem has nothing to do with cython; it's just that `np.empty` expects the first argument to be the shape given as an int or tuple of ints. The second argument is interpreted as the dtype:

```
In [19]: np.empty(5,5)
TypeError: data type not understood
```

while `np.empty((5,5))` returns an empty array of shape (5,5).
So instead use

```
 cdef np.ndarray[double,ndim=2,mode='c'] onsite=np.empty((n+1,n+1))
```

Note the double set of parentheses around `n+1, n+1`. Or, use `np.zeros` instead of `np.empty` to make the Cython function match the Python function.

PS: When debugging Python, it is helpful to note not only the error message, but the line that raises the exception:

```
  File "comp.pyx", line 13, in comp.set_onsite (comp.c:1290)
    cdef np.ndarray[double,ndim=2,mode='c'] onsite=np.empty(n+1,n+1)
TypeError: data type not understood
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works. But I have another question. I calculate the time. The results are pretty close. So is there anyway I can do to make it faster by using cython?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of a way to improve the performance. You might want to ask a new question, though, since I don't know Cython very well.